# Birthday problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector-problem

Recently I read about how many people it takes for the probability that two or more share the same birthday to be sufficiently high.

**My question**: How many people do I have to know that I could be sufficiently sure (>95%) that I have to congratulate at least one person every day for the whole year, that is, all 365 days?

Comment: This is a version of the [Coupon Collector problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector), not the Birthday problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware the problem already existed.

Comment: I provide a full analysis of this distribution for a generalization of the problem at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/202393/919 .  At the end I also give an approximation to the value you seek (use $p=1$ in your case). That approximation gives 3247 people.  It should be pretty accurate.  The `R` program `mean(replicate(1e4, 365==length(union(integer(0), floor(runif(3247)*365)))))` simulates 10,000 instances of this situation (within a few seconds) and consistently produces answers close to 95%.